# Change Alt-Right/Let shortcut in Windows to go to beginning/end of line like macOS

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, remapping

In macOS, using command+right/left will go to the beginning or end of the current line of text. This was extremely useful when typing or coding in general, but in Windows, Alt+Left/Right has totally different behavior depending on the app. Is there any way to globally change this to only be used a text shortcut for nevigating text lines?

Or is there a way to remap the Alt+Left/Right shortcut key to the home/end keys? (home/end keys performs the beginning/end of line feature from macOS)

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I was able to figure it out. You can use Windows PowerToys, go into the Keyboard Manager settings, and easily remap any key combination to a single button. I just remapped Alt+Left/Right to the home and end keys.

[PowerToys GitHub (install from here)](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)

[This article explains the PowerToys keyboard settings page.](https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Thanks - this worked a treat on my AWS Workspace instance which is running Windows Server 10.